# what's the purpose of composer's `require` command

Tags: composer-php

Here is the definitions from the docs:

> The require command adds new packages to the composer.json file from
>   the current directory. If no file exists one will be created on the
>   fly. After adding/changing the requirements, the modified requirements
>   will be installed or updated.
>
> If you do not want to choose requirements interactively, you can just
>   pass them to the command.

I can't seem to understand the purpose of the `require` command and the difference from `install`. Can you elaborate on that?

And here is the example of using the command:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
```

Can you tell me what's the difference from:

```
composer global install "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It's just a convention**. There might be some fallbacks in other commands for common people missuses, but every command is optimized for a different feature. It's just better user experience.

Same goes for similarity of `composer install` and `composer update`.

As for conventions, in order of common workflow:

- [`composer install`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install) is for installing **all packages** of new application (all mentioned in `composer.json`), use: `composer install`
- [`composer require`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) is for adding **a new package**, use: `composer require symfony/symfony`
- `composer update` is for updating current dependencies, use: `composer update`

Comment: thanks, what's the difference between `adding` and `installing` new package as mentioned in your examples?

Comment: I've updated the answer so it's clear what to use when.

Comment: thanks, but still, `composer require is for adding a new package,` - adding where? and `require` also installs packages as written in the docs. I'd be great if you provided an example of the usage of `require` vs `install`

Comment: > "adding where"? To `composer.json`, `/vendor` dir and is autoloaded in `/vendor/autoload.php`.
> "usage of require vs install". In practice I use only `composer require package/package` and `composer update`.

What exactly do you try to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, so is `require` essentially an install that also adds a dependency to `composer.json`? Something like `bower install --save-dev`? For example, if there is no `package-dep` in my `composer.json` and I do `composer require package-dep` it will be added to `composer.json` and installed?

Comment: Well, I just ran `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"` from the directory with `composer.json`, and after the plugin was installed I checked `composer.json` and the dependency wasn't added there, why?

Comment: It because `composer` != `composer global`. It will install to the composer's global `/vendor/` dir, see [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global).

Comment: thanks, so `composer global` doesn't update any `composer.json`?

Comment: thanks, where can I find it? I don't seem to locate it in `composer` home dir

Comment: What's in your `composer` home dir?

Comment: sorry, it's there, just got confused with the folders. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score -1):

**composer require**->It will write the modules in composer.json file and install the module.

**composer install**->It will install the modules which are already present in the composer.json file.